# How am I supposed to expand $\sin^2 A + \sin^4 A = 1$ into $1 + \sin^2A = \tan^2A$?

Tags: trigonometry

My question is how can i expand
$$\sin^2 A + \sin^4 A = 1$$
into:
$$1 + \sin^2A = \tan^2A$$

I tried quite a few ways I know but all of them kinda felt random. i am not sure how to share my trials here. I am quite beginner in trigonometry. it is one of the extra test question from my textbook. I don't need it but cant control curiosity. so pls help me.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
found the solution, dropping it here, 
\begin{align}
\sin^2 A + \sin^4 A & = 1 \\
\sin^4 A & = 1 - sin^2 A \\
\sin^2 A . \sin^2 A & = cos^2 A \\
\sin^2 A . (1 - \cos^2 A) & = cos^2 A \\
\sin^2 A - \sin^2 A.\cos^2 A & = cos^2 A \\
\sin^2 A & = cos^2 A + \sin^2 A.\cos^2 A \\
\sin^2 A & = \cos^2 A(1 + \sin^2 A) \\
1 + \sin^2 A & = \cfrac{\sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A} \\
1 + \sin^2 A & = \tan^2 A \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\sin^2A + \sin^4A = 1 \implies \sin^4A = \cos^2 A$

Can you proceed from here?

Additional Info

$$\sin^2A(1-\cos^2A) = \cos^2A$$

$$\sin^2A = \cos^2A + \sin^2A\cos^2A$$

Divide by $\cos^2 A$

Comment: i was able to prove this, but dont know how to proceed. pls help

Comment: i got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin^2 A = 1 - \sin^4 A$$ $$ \sin^2A= (1 - \sin^2 A)(1 + \sin^2 A) $$ $$\sin^2 A= (\cos^2 A) (1 + \sin^2 A)$$ $$\therefore \tan^2 A = 1 + \sin^2 A$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit! It can fit in one line but you showed me that it looks better like this.

Comment: And also nice proof       +1

Comment: Yep, I thought about it for quite a while. It's certainly nicer than the book's solution.

Comment: Nice ...........

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\sin^2A=a,$  we have $a+a^2=1$

We need $$1+a=\dfrac a{1-a}$$

As $1-a\ne0,1+1^2\ne1$  $$\iff a=(1-a)(1+a)\iff a=1-a^2\iff a+a^2=1$$

Done!